# Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySQL DBContext throwing "Unqualified data type char" exception

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am trying to port an existing application from EF 6 and MySQL.Data.Entity.EF6 to EF Core and Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.

When the DBContext creates its model, it throws an ArgumentException with message "Unqualified data type char."

I can reproduce the error in a brand-new Console project. As soon as I add a DBSet<Site> to my DBContext, where Site is a class from my existing project's Database.Entities dll, the validation error appears.

Abbreviated stack trace:

```
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlTypeMappingSource.ValidateMapping(CoreTypeMapping mapping, IProperty property)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTypeMappingSource.FindMappingWithConversion(RelationalTypeMappingInfo& mappingInfo, IReadOnlyList`1 principals)
   ...
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator validator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
   ...
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_Model()
```

The existing class is pretty simple. It looks like this (actually, the Id is inherited from a base class):

```
public class Site {
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Required]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ApplicationId")]
    public virtual Application Application { get; set; }
    [Column("ApplicationId")]
    [Required]
    public string ApplicationId { get; set; }
}
```

Is there something about the way the existing Dll is compiled that affects this?  Can I override something in OnModelCreating to avoid this error? Is there any way to get further insight into what property is being seen as "char"?

Comment: Is there some code in `OnModelCreating` not shown here? Something like `.HasColumnType("char")`?

Comment: @IvanStoev - OnModelCreating currently sets up Indexes.  Nothing about Column Type.  Typical entry:

                modelBuilder.Entity<DE.Site>()
                .HasIndex(s => new { s.Identifier, s.ApplicationId })  
   .HasName("IX_SiteIdentifierAndAppicationId")
                .IsUnique();

Comment: There must be a string `"char"` somewhere in your code. Unfortunately EF Core exception message won't give you that info, you need to find it.

Comment: Aha!  Yes, the linked object, Application, has a column defined as column type "char," via an annotation on the property: [Column(TypeName = "char")].   So, one option would be to change such classes.  Is there an alternative to override this in OnModelBuilding?

Comment: It can be left there, but EF Core requires qualifying the length, e.g. `char(20)`